# Which of the following real numbers are algebraic?

Tags: abstract-algebra

A real number is said to be *algebraic* if it is root of a non-zero polynomial with integer coeﬃcients.

> Which of the following real numbers are algebraic?
>
> (a) $\cos (\pi/5)$
> (b) $e^{\frac{1}{2}\log2}$
> (c) $5^{1/7}+7^{1/5}$

---

(a) I am not sure.
(b) it is algebraic since this is $\sqrt{2}$ and $x^2-2$ is the polynomial.
(c) not sure but I think this is also algebraic and a polynomial og order 35 may be the answer.but I cant prove this.

can I get some help please.

Comment: $(a)$ http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/49297/the-only-two-rational-values-for-cosine-and-their-connection-to-the-kummer-rings

Comment: Assuming natural logarithm, $$e^{\frac12\log 2}=e^{\log\sqrt2}=\sqrt2$$

Comment: The sum of two algebraic numbers is algebraic. If these were questions in an exam you took, or are on a practice exam, then you should probably know this fact and how to prove it. (Also note $\cos\pi/5$ is a sum of two algebraic numbers.) One doesn't need to find an explicit polynomial.

Comment: Chiming in with anon. $e^{i\pi/5}$ is a root of $x^5+1=0$, so it is algebraic. Same holds for $e^{-i\pi/5}$. Thus $\cos(\pi/5)$ which is their average is algebraic also (dividing by two gives another algebraic, the polynomial won't be monic this time). Note that replacing $5$ with a larger integer poses no problem, if you think about it in this way.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct on (b).

For (a) and (c), the key facts are that a sum, quotient and product of algebraic numbers are algebraic. (You need to prove this if you haven't yet!)

$$\cos (\pi/5)=\frac{ \zeta_{10}+\zeta_{10}^{-1}}2$$ where $\zeta_{10}$ is a $10$th root of unity, and (c) is plainly obvious from the key facts.

Answer (score 0):

(a) Since 
$$\alpha=\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{5}\right)=\frac{1+\sqrt 5}{4}\Rightarrow 4\alpha-1=\sqrt 5\Rightarrow (4\alpha-1)^2=5,$$
you'll know that $x=\alpha$ is a root of 
$$4x^2-2x-1=0.$$

(c) Wolfram alpha gives us [this](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=5%5E%281/7%29%2b7%5E%281/5%29).

Comment: but how can I check in exam?

Comment: You mean how we can get $\cos(\pi/5)=(1+\sqrt 5)/4$?

Comment: for both.In (a) if 5 is repleced by any other large iteger then what should we do?

Comment: for (c) in exam how to check this types of equations without any software?

Comment: It is known that $\cosα$ is a transcendental number if $α\not=0$ is an algebraic number. For $(c)$, I don't know any good way to check it without using computer. By the way, if you want to get $\cos(\pi/5)=(1+\sqrt 5)/4$, then consider an isosceles triangle $ABC$ with $\angle{ABC}=\angle{ACB}=36^\circ,$ and take $D$ on $BC$ such that $\angle{BAD}=72^\circ$.

Answer (score -2):

(c) this is a solution of 35x7 deg polynomial
when we solve :  x-5^(1/7)=7^(1/5)
raising 35 power
x^35 - 5^5 - 7^7 = 5^(1/7)*(polynomial of degree 34)

again raising 7th power we get desired polynomial.

(a) refer wolfram alpha.

Comment: Raising $x-5^{1/7}=7^{1/5}$ to $35$ does not give us $x^{35}-5^5-7^7=5^{1/7}$. Why would you think that?

Comment: it seems that you didn't got my point.I have given a hint,its not complete sol and i don't see any reason to downvote

Comment: The downvote (not from me, because you are new) is because your hint is **incorrect**, not incomplete. That's what my comment was saying, so it looks like you didn't get *my* point. There's also the difficult-to-read formatting to consider.