# if $\cos{(a\pi)}=\frac{1}{3}$, then $a $ is irrational

Tags: number-theory

> If $$\cos{(a\pi)}=\dfrac{1}{3}$$
>   then show that ：$a$ is irrational

this result seems easy,but I can't prove it. Thank you...

Comment: See page 2 of http://arxiv.org/pdf/1006.2938.pdf , or the answer to http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/49297/the-only-two-rational-values-for-cosine-and-their-connection-to-the-kummer-rings , depending on the tools you want to use.

Comment: isn't enough for you to say that $\frac{arccos(\frac13)}{\pi}$ is not rational because $arccos(\frac13)$ is not a multiple of $\pi$?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/87768), it is shown that $\sin(a\pi)$ and $a$ are both rational if and only if $|\sin(a\pi)|\in\{0,\frac12,1\}$. Since $\cos(a\pi)=\sin((\frac12-a)\pi)$, the same is true for $\cos(a\pi)$ and $a$.

We can adjust the proof as follows:

Note that $e^{\pm ip\pi/q}$ is an algebraic integer since
$$
\left(e^{\pm ip\pi/q}\right)^{2q}-1=0
$$
Since $2\cos(p\pi/q)=e^{ip\pi/q}+e^{-ip\pi/q}$ is the sum of two algebraic integers, it is an algebraic integer and is rational if and only if it is an integer. The only integers possible are $\{-2,-1,0,1,2\}$. Thus, the only possibilities for $\cos(p\pi/q)$ to be rational would be $\{-1,-\frac12,0,\frac12,1\}$.